# Pattern to extract all matches of URLs within a string

Tags: regex, vba

I have some URLs like this `http://app14.co.ad.local:90/ATT\me1111419.org` within a string.
The numbers of dots `.` and backslash `\` or forward slash `/` is not constant.
The URLs start with `"http`" and end with a dot+("org" , "com", "net")

| Strings | expected result |
| --- | --- |
| Read me [http://app14.co.ad.local:90/ATT\\me1111419.org](http://app14.co.ad.local:90/ATT%5C%5Cme1111419.org) blasss test wwww [http://app14.co.ad.local:90/ATT\\me1.111.com](http://app14.co.ad.local:90/ATT%5C%5Cme1.111.com) xxxxbb aaa qwer fff [http://app14.co.ad.local:90/ATT\\bbb1419.net](http://app14.co.ad.local:90/ATT%5C%5Cbbb1419.net) www | [http://app14.co.ad.local:90/ATT\\me1111419.org](http://app14.co.ad.local:90/ATT%5C%5Cme1111419.org) http://app14.co.ad.local:90/ATT\me1.111.com http://app14.co.ad.local:90/ATT\b.bb1.419.net |

the below code will work correctly only if my string contains only URLs and no other words.
my problem with the pattern itself.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Function RegexMatches(strInput As String) As String

    Dim re As New RegExp
    Dim rMatch As Object, s As String, arrayMatches(), i As Long

     With re
       .Pattern = "(http:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?"
       .Global = True
       .MultiLine = True
       .IgnoreCase = True
     End With
    
     If re.test(strInput) Then
        For Each rMatch In re.Execute(strInput)
            ReDim Preserve arrayMatches(i)
            arrayMatches(i) = rMatch.Value
            i = i + 1
        Next
     End If
    
    RegexMatches = Join(arrayMatches, vbLf)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
http://            # Match 'http://'
\S+                # followed by one or more non-whitespace characters
\.(?:net|com|org)  # then either '.net', '.com' or '.org'.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/e2Q6u0/2).